# Creating/Assigning Roles, Claims and Policies in Active Directory to users

Tags: c#, active-directory, authorization, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I need to create a leave system(Blazor Server App) that uses windows authentication. I need to restrict users based on their roles or policies. I also need to specify a user which will be the person approving the leave for that user(maybe i need a claim called approver and value will be the user's username?). In my blazor server app i can restrict routes and controls from viewing based on the users role or policy. how do I create and assign roles, claims and policies to users in Active Directory?

Any help would be grateful.

I managed to get the IT guy to create the users but he doesn't know how to add roles, claims and policies. however he said he can add attributes.

Comment: Well typically a user logs into your app with a username and password.
Then you check if the user existis in your database and get the roles for the user and your app handles these roles. When you are using AD on IIS for example the user claims can already be handled by IIS and Windows Auth so you don't have to handle the getting yourself. Or you could take the SID and query the AD in the App. 
You could build your roles around what the AD already offers or build your own. 
It is kinda hard to answer such a broad question.